# Is there a function in Roomle to import a Layout, that i want to change ? (.dwg, .dxf,)

Tags: roomle

i want to import a Layout in Roomle, but i can only see the function to make it myself. Is there a function to import a ".dwg" or a ".dxf"
We have the task to change a existing Layout in Roomle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to import a plan into Roomle using a .dwg or .dxf file.

You can change an existing plan in the iOS App or in the Web App (https://www.roomle.com/app/login).

Comment: Thanks for the fast message. One last question. How do i import the plan to change in the Web App